# How can I choose option from this dropdown menu on this website

Tags: excel, vba, dom, web-scraping, html-table

I am working in vba and trying fill in the form in this website and get the output [Link Here](https://applications.icao.int/icec)

There is a problem when i try to fill in the input box from/to airport. This is what i have tried: This function is being called to fill in from/to airport fields

```
Function enter_get_name(ByVal iedoc As HTMLDocument, _
                    ByVal input_box As String, ByVal iata As String, _
                    ByVal id As String, ByRef str As Variant) As Boolean
Dim noopt       As Integer       ' length of string that appear on drop down menu if no option available
noopt = Len("If your destination does not appear among the cities listed in the destination box")

iedoc.getElementsByName(input_box)(0).innerText = iata                 ' enter string
Set drop_down = iedoc.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("li")
Do While drop_down.Length = 0: DoEvents: Loop     ' wait for the drop down menu to come up

If Len(drop_down(0).innerText) = noopt Then  ' if option do not exist
    enter_get_name = False                             ' return value
    Exit Function                                       ' exit
Else
    For Each Name In drop_down       ' loop all options of drop down menu
        ' if found a exact same IATA code, click that html element
        str = Mid(Name.innerText, Len(Name.innerText) - 4, 3)
        If StrComp(iata, str, 1) = 0 Then
            Name.Click
        Exit For
        End If
    Next

    enter_get_name = True
End If
End Function
```

So I have tried to loop all options available in the dropdown, find that element, then click it. The code can find the element successfully, but when i try to .click that element, it does not work sometimes. For example, i have a flight From HKG To SIN as input.

There is 2 options for the arrival(TO) airport: HEL and SIN, it somehow clicked HEL. However, if i do it the other way around, ie: From SIN to HKG, there is no problem with selecting SIN with 10+ options available. How can i resolve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See the answers here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54107030/how-to-fill-in-html-autocomplete-fields-using-vba/54108777#54108777

Comment: It doesn't work. Both answers are choosing the first option on the drop down menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following uses regex to search the suggested list for the right entry and then click. I'd like to knock out some of the admittedly short hardcoded delays but haven't yet seen a reliable way to ensure dropdown list is fully populated , given it is continuously populated from ajax calls, without such measures.

```
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim d As WebDriver, i As Long, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    Const Url = "https://applications.icao.int/icec"
    Const FROM As String = "HKG"
    Const GOING_TO  As String = "SIN"
    Dim re As Object

    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get Url
        .FindElementByCss("[name=frm1]").SendKeys FROM

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

        Dim fromSelection As Object
        t = Timer
        Do
            Set fromSelection = .FindElementsByCss("#ui-id-1 li")
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While fromSelection.Count = 0

        If .FindElementsByCss("#ui-id-1 li").Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

        If .FindElementsByCss("#ui-id-1 li").Count = 1 Then
            .FindElementsByCss("#ui-id-1 li").item(1).Click
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            For i = 1 To .FindElementsByCss("#ui-id-1 li").Count
                If MatchFound(re, .FindElementsByCss("#ui-id-1 li").item(i).Text, "\(" & FROM & "[ \t]\)") Then
                    .FindElementsByCss("#ui-id-1 li").item(i).Click
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If

        .FindElementByCss("[name=to1]").SendKeys GOING_TO

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

        Dim toSelection As Object
        t = Timer
        Do
            Set toSelection = .FindElementsByCss("#ui-id-2 li")
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While toSelection.Count = 0

        If .FindElementsByCss("#ui-id-2 li").Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

        If .FindElementsByCss("#ui-id-2 li").Count = 1 Then
            .FindElementsByCss("#ui-id-2 li").item(1).Click
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            For i = 1 To .FindElementsByCss("#ui-id-2 li").Count
                If MatchFound(re, .FindElementsByCss("#ui-id-2 li").item(i).Text, "\(" & GOING_TO & "[ \t]\)") Then
                    .FindElementsByCss("#ui-id-2 li").item(i).Click
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

        .FindElementById("computeByInput").Click

        Stop                                     'delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub

Public Function MatchFound(ByVal re As Object, ByVal inputString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As Boolean
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .pattern = pattern
        If .test(inputString) Then
            MatchFound = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With
    MatchFound = "False"
End Function
```

Comment: yeah it worked! But can you explain why .FindElementsByCss("#ui-id-2 li").item(i).Click work but my solution don't? both of them are using .click. and choosing the same element.

Comment: The dropdown continuously updates with substring matches for what you are entering. With your second entry there are two matches for the substring found. My regex actually looks for the correct item out of the possible items, looping until it is found (given dynamically entered)